# Difficulty Customizing Theme Colors in Compose Multiplatform App

Tags: color-scheme, multiplatform, theming

I am currently working on a Compose multiplatform app and encountering some hurdles with theme customization, specifically regarding altering the theme colors. Unlike in native Android Jetpack Compose apps where this process seems more straightforward, I am finding it challenging to implement theme color changes effectively in the multiplatform environment.

I have explored various documentation and resources but have not found a clear solution that fits the multiplatform setup. Has anyone successfully managed to customize theme colors in a Compose multiplatform app? if so, could you please share your insights, approaches, or any helpful resources?

Any guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance.